# Function pointer to memberfunction of other instace

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

```
class A
{
private:
    int _i;

    int calc() { return i; }

public:
    int (*get)() = &A::calc;

    A(int i){ _i = i; }
    A(A *a ) { get = a->get; }
};

int main(){
    A a = new A(5);
    A b = new A(a)
}
```

Hi, I think I have a kind of special question. I dont know the right tag, so I try to descripe best possible:

There is a class `A` with a function `calc` and a function pointer `get` with equal footprint of calc. Typically get should be refer to `calc` of its own instance but for special condition it should be redirected to `calc` of an other instance. Is there a way to implement it?

Thank you. (syntax is pseudocode)

edit: Background is that `calc` does some complex calculations with a lot of different member variables and I only want to get the result

Comment: What is the `B` class? What's the current error that you get?

Comment: Sry, this was a typo.

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what do you need this for? It seems like you are trying to invent polymorphism or something like a [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). In either case you probably need to use [virtual functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual) instead of member function pointers.

Comment: Calc does some complex calculations with a lot of different member variables and I only want to get the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sure:

```
std::function<int()> get = std::bind(&A::calc, this);
```

later, you can change it to point to the other instance "b":

```
get = std::bind(&A::calc, &b)
```

Also note that your code would not compile as you are attempting to assign a member function pointer (&A::calc) to a plain function pointer (int(*)()). The syntax for declaring member function pointer would be int(A::*get)(), but then you would only be able to invoke that member function pointer if you have an instance on your hand (unless you bind it like in the solution I provided above).

```
instance.*get();

or

pointer ->* get();
```

Note the use of .* and ->* operators